# XElement.Load doesn't load the path

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I have a path starting with the common C:\Users...\myXmlFile.xml and I am trying to load it with the

```
XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\...\myXmlFile.xml")
```

but it doesn load it and it says:

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

I found out what's the reason and I can not solve it.The thing is that in some of the folders that I have in the path there is a folder with spaces and dashes between the words. Example **C:\users\my - folder - doesnt - work\otherFolder\myXmlFile.xml**

it works when I remove the spaces.

Comment: Try loading any proper XML... I feel your XML is corrupted.

Comment: Please, show content of `myXmlFile.xml`

Comment: Yes.There was something wrong with the file.Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Spaces and dashes in path do not affect xml loading. If there would be some problem with finding file, you'd see `FileNotFoundException`. Thus error says there is wrong data in first position of first line, I think your xml file even do not have tag (which should start from `<` symbol) at the beginning of file.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\...\myXmlFile.xml");
if(file.Exists)
{
   XElement root = XElement.Load(file.Fullname);
   ...
}
else
   throw new FileNotFoundException(file.Fullname);
```